# Sqoop import failing with exception interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBWritable not org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.DBWritable

Tags: import, mapreduce, hive, teradata, sqoop

I have to migrate code from teradata to hive.. while importing data from Teradata using sqoop, its failing
   with below error:

```
ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: 
java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: interface 
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBWritable not 
org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.DBWritable         
at com.cloudera.sqoop.teradata.imports.TeradataImportJob.configureInputFormat(TeradataImportJob.java:111)         
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:231)        
at com.cloudera.sqoop.teradata.TeradataManager.importTable(TeradataManager.java:86)         
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:413)         
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:502)         
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)         
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)         
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)         
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)         
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)         
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)
```

Anyone faced any issue like this?

Comment: What is the sqoop script that you are using to so the import.

Comment: sqoop import --connect jdbc:teradata://IPaddress/SLSORDDB --username userid --password ***** --table tablename --hive-import --hive-table tablename                                                                                                             It is connecting to database but once it begins with importing data it is failing with the error mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the version of the teradata connector that you are using. Try using a different version of the connector jar. I have faced an issue with importing from MySQL table and changing to an earlier version of MySQL connector fixed my issue.